# I want to run a method every minute that's started from my OnAppearing(). Do I need to run this as a task?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timer

Here's the code that I have come up with. It seems to work but I am concerned that it may not be good way to do what I want to do.  What I need is to run a method every minute as soon as the OnAppearing happens and have it stop with the OnDisappearing();

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   BindingContext = vm;

   cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   if (Settings.mode == MO.Practice)
   {
      if (!App.stopWatch.IsRunning) { App.stopWatch.Start(); }
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), () =>
      {
          if (App.stopWatch.IsRunning && App.stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= 60)
          {
             // Here's the method I want to run. After it's finished
             // I call BeginInvoke .. to update info on the screen
             if (App.DB.ReducePoints() == true)
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                   vm.PifInfo = GetPifInfo();
                });
                App.stopWatch.Restart();
             }
             return true;
            });
        }
        await GetCards(cts.Token);
    }
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    Unsubscribe();
    cts.Cancel();
    if (App.stopWatch.IsRunning) { App.stopWatch.Stop(); }
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Not part of the question but I would welcome any comments on the code also.

Comment: Move logic in another class and calls `NewClass.StartTimer()` in `OnAppearing` and `NewClass.StopTimer()` in `OnDisappearing()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this simpler by returning the correct value from `Device.StartTimer`, to repeat `true`, to not repeat `false` and not use a `StopWatch`. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms) states that `While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring.` And as you see from the source, the method doesn't need a `Func<Task<bool>>` it only needs a `Func<bool>` callback so there is no need to use a `Task`.)

**in the class**

```
volatile bool run;
```

**in OnAppearing**

```
run = true;
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), () => {
if (run) { /*do what you want;*/ return true; }
else { return false; }
});
```

**in OnDisappearing**

```
run = false;
```

---

### EDIT - as requested by OP

Here is the code. I am leaving my original answer to help anyone else who needs this.

```
volatile bool run;

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   BindingContext = vm;    
   cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   if (Settings.mode == MO.Practice)
   {
        run = true;
        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), () => 
        {
            if (run) 
            { 
                 if (App.DB.ReducePoints() == true)
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                       vm.PifInfo = GetPifInfo();
                    });
                 return true; 
            }
            else { return false; }
        });
        await GetCards(cts.Token);
    }
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    run = false;
    Unsubscribe();
    cts.Cancel();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example using all the code in the question so can people can more easily see what you mean.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 Yes. I did that.

Comment: @Alan2 for the record I would suggest you avoid async void on non-event handlers that can destabilise your application.

Comment: @Alan2 I added some information to my first paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

You can refactor the code to make proper use of the Timer in combination with a `CancellationToken`.

Also note the use of the async event handler to avoid the fire and forget call to `async void OnAppearing` that won't allow thrown exceptions to be caught and can cause crashes.

```
CancellationTokenSource source;

protected override void OnAppearing() {
    base.OnAppearing();
    BindingContext = vm;
    timerStarted += onTimerStarted;
    timerStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private event EventHandler timerStarted = delegate { };

private async void onTimerStarted(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    timerStarted -= onTimerStarted;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    if (Settings.mode == MO.Practice) {
        source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        StartTimer(source.Token);
        await GetCards(cts.Token);
    }
}

private void StartTimer(CancellationToken token) {        
    var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    Func<bool> callback = () => {
        //check if to stop timer
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return false;
        //Code to be repeated
        checkPoints();            
        //While the callback returns true, the timer will keep recurring.
        return true;
    };
    //repeat this function every minute
    Device.StartTimer(interval, callback);
}

private void checkPoints() {
    // Here's the method I want to run. After it's finished
    // I call BeginInvoke .. to update info on the screen
    if (App.DB.ReducePoints() == true) {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            vm.PifInfo = GetPifInfo();
        });
    }
}

protected override void OnDisappearing() {        
    source.Cancel();//Timer will short-circuit on next interval
    Unsubscribe();
    cts.Cancel();        
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

The cancellation token will be used to force the timer to return `false` and stop recurring when the token is cancelled in `OnDisappearing()`.

If the function to be repeated needs to be asynchronous add another async event handler to manage that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Rx.Timer for that:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   _sub = Observable.Timer(0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
           .ObserveOnDispatcher() // move invocation to dispatcher
           .Do(_ => {
                  vm.PifInfo = GetPifInfo(); // do your work. Try/catch will be usefull, otherwise any exception will break the subscription
            })
       //    .Retry() // uncomment this if you want to immedietally try again after a failure, no try/catch then
           .Subscribe();

    ....

}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   _sub?.Dispose(); // this will unsubscribe to the timer
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a new class that is responsible to do the timed check.

with a boolean property continueChecking. It does a sleep, then calls a different method to do the work, then checks if it has to continue checking. if so, it calls itself.

In the onDisappearing you set the continueChecking to false, so the method stops calling itself.

By doing so you split the concern of starting and ending the loop, the loop itself and the work it has to do in three separate places.

Edit: code example

```cs
public class ButtonClicked
    {
        //make sure you've got the same instance on both methods
        private Loop loop = new Loop();

        protected async void OnAppearing()
        {
            //other work
            await loop.StartLoop();
        }

        protected void OnDisappearing()
        {
            //other work
            loop.StopLoop();
        }
    }

    public class Loop
    {
        private bool _continueChecking;
        private readonly TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);

        public async Task StartLoop()
        {
            await DoLoop();
        }
        public void StopLoop()
        {
            _continueChecking = false;
        }

        private async Task DoLoop()
        {
            _continueChecking = true;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval);
                TheWork();
            });
            if (_continueChecking)
            {
                DoLoop();
            }
        }


        private void TheWork()
        {
           //specific work stuff
           //can be anywhere so it is testable and reusable
        }
    }
```